# onclick function replicates after edit HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have inside my html view a list of articles with a link like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="open_modal(event,11)">Article info</a>
```

The function open_modal() is suppoused to launch a bootstrap modal and populate it with the information of the article with id = 11 via ajax (the "event" parameter is to preventDefault()). But when I edit the HTML directly on the browser(F12) and change the id with another(ex. 10), when the modal is launched, it is populated with the information of article 11 and article 10 below it... And so on... It's like the function is triggering for each time I've edited the id on the HTML... Why is that happening? is there some javascript concept that I'm missing?

The code for open_modal() is like this:

```
function open_modal(event, id){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#modal").modal("show");
    $.ajax({
        url: the-url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'id' : id },
        success: function(response) {
            // Here I append the response inside the modal
            $('#modal .modal-dialog').append(response);
        },
        error: function(){
            // Do something
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what is going on without the rest of the code. Can you post the code for `open_modal`?

Comment: The open_modal() function is working right, I've tested it. I just wanna know why is that bug happening?

Comment: What appears as the modal's content if you just do, in the console, `$("#modal").modal("show")`?

Comment: you are appending response. you should use **$('#modal .modal-dialog').html(response);**

Comment: as above. Append just keeps adding something to the bottom of the list (leaving the rest of the list above intact). use `html` if you want to *replace* the content.

Comment: @TheDude I dont understand the question, the modal is suppoused to have the info on 1 article, but instead is showing 2 articles... I've added a console.log() inside the open_modal() function and noticed that it's triggering for each time I've edited the HTML via inspect element(F12)

Answer (score 0):

Empty the modal content first:

```
$('#modal .modal-dialog').empty().append(response);
```